# Is the waveform the "raw" audio data? (Pytorch)

Tags: python, audio, pytorch

I am using PyTorch in an audio deep learning project. I am using the `torchaudio.load` [method](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/audio_preprocessing_tutorial.html#loading-audio-data-into-tensor) to load the waveform and sample rate. Now, my question is, is the waveform considered the "raw" audio data? Is it the [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) data? If not, then how can I get PCM data from `.ogg` format?

Comment: From what I read from wikipedia, the PCM is just the standard way analog data is represented in a computer. And you can't get more "raw" than that.

Comment: @Fra93 is the waveform returned from the `load` method considered to be the PCM data? Kind of confused

Comment: From pytorch documentation and plot (the link you provided) it seems so. By raw data I mean the sampled vector x(n) from a continuous vector x(t). You can't represent x in a computer, you need to sample in time and in amplitude (quantization). You represent it as a discrete vector, where each sample is separated from the next one by a factor of 1/fs, where fs is the sampling frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Yes, it's raw data.

For the explanation read below. If you know about sampling theory and how sound is generated, skip to the last paragraph.

### PCM

PCM is a fancy way to explain the process by which a continuous time wave is represented inside a computer. You can learn more in any introductory course/book of digital signal processing such [chapter 3](https://users.dimi.uniud.it/%7Eantonio.dangelo/MMS/materials/Guide_to_Digital_Signal_Process.pdf) of The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing.

Briefly in a computer you can only represent finite quantities, so you need to take discrete samples in time (sampling) at a certain amplitudes (quantization).

When loading any audio file this process has been already done for you.

### RAW DATA

If you connect a speaker and you play a wave, the membrane will oscillate as the amplitude of such wave at every instant. This is the "raw" audio, a signal that contains the amplitude at each "time" instant. If you can "see" the wave changing with no discontinuity from left to right when plotting your data, it is very likely a raw vector.

What is non-raw data then? Every compression algorithm modifies the input vector with any sort of mathematical function, so that it occupies less space, but also is not understandable anymore by just looking at it. This is because the samples don't represent anymore an amplitude over time. If you'd play the compressed wave through a speaker you wouldn't get any sound, only noise.

### Pytorch

In the example you provided from the pytorch documentation we can clearly see that the plot represents raw data, sampled at 16kHz.

To exclude the possibility that

- `torchaudio.load` could still give a sort of compressed object
- the raw data is generated and plotted by `plot_waveform`

We can see that the `waveform` variable is long `54400` samples and sampled at 16kHz. This means it represents 54400*(1/16000) seconds, which are exactly 3.4s.

The plot shows 3.4seconds, thus telling us that what is represented in the variable `waveform` returned by the load function is the raw data.